# Java взаимодействие потоков

Tags: java, многопоточность

возник такой вопрос
Почему у меня поток, который я передаю в классе CalculateThread не возобновляет свою работу, когда метод run() выполнился.

```
public class CalculateThread extends Thread {
    CalculateThread(Thread a) {
        synchronized (a) {
            try {
                a.wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        synchronized (Main.a){
            Main.a.sqrtX = Main.a.x * Main.a.x;
        }
        synchronized (this){
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот класс объекта, который я передаю в сам поток CalculateThread

```
public class MainThread extends Thread {

    public void run(){
        Main.a = new MyObject();
        int key;
        do {
            System.out.println("1 - Ввести число.");
            System.out.println("2 - Получить квадрат числа.");
            System.out.println("0 - Выход.");
            key = Main.EnterNumber();
            switch(key){
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Введите число: ");
                    Main.a.x = Main.EnterNumber();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    CalculateThread obj = new CalculateThread(this);
                    obj.start();
                    System.out.println("Квадрат числа " + Main.a.x + " равняется " + Main.a.sqrtX);
                    break;
                case 0:
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Выберите одно из списка.");
                    break;
        }
    }while (key != 0);
}
```

}

И сам объект MyObject, над которым у меня проводятся вычисления

```
public class MyObject {
    int x;
    int sqrtX;

    MyObject(){
        x = 0;
        sqrtX = 0;
    }

    MyObject(int x){
        this.x = x;
        sqrtX = 0;
    }
}
```

Буду благодарен за любой совет, т.к. только начал разбираться в потоках.

Comment: попробуй вызвать `notifyAll()` на том же объекте, на котором вызывал `wait()`. Просто `notify()` будит рандомный поток, а не обязательно тот, который ты усыпил с помощью `wait()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конструкторе класса CalculateThread вы останавливаете поток MainThread до того, как выполняется запуск этого потока в MainThread obj.start(); Так что поток не запускается и notify не выполняется. Вообще структура классов странная.

Comment: Добавил в метод run() остановку потока и все заработало, спасибо)
А что собственно не так со структурой классов? Я просто недавно только начал заниматься всем этим делом

Comment: Не совсем понятно зачем в Main поле MyObject a да еще и статическое. Его надо объявлять там где оно используется. Зачем один поток передается в другой. На мой взгляд лучше было бы ими управлять из вне. Ну и конструкции типа Main.a.x режут глаз. Их стоит избегать. Используйте сеттеры геттеры.

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет)